# MariaDB Root Password

Tags: mariadb

`In order to log in to MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current password for the root user. If you've just installed MariaDB, and haven't set the root password yet, you should just press enter here.`

I haven't set a root password, so I pressed enter. All that happened is the dialogue box repeated itself as if I entered an incorrect password.

Comment: Well, yes, empty password is incorrect password.

Comment: I've run that from the command line, not sure what dialog box?

Comment: How did you install the MariaDD ?

Comment: Are we talking about the system's root password or MariaDB's root password? And what did you do for your dialog to pop up? In short: what is the context of your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must be logged in as the root user to enter empty password